# How to animate my GIF tilesheet (OpenGL, DevIL, C++)

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to animate a gif in my window by making it scroll to each frame on my tilesheet but it currently stays on only one frame. I assume it's because I'm not limiting the fps on the gif but I have no clue how to do that. Anyone?

@max66 I'm trying to obtain an animation by doing this. I'm trying to make it go down the y axis on the texture(which is a sprite tile sheet) which works without the if statement so far but it freezes on the last frame.

My (newish) code:

```
#include "LUtil.h"
#include <IL/il.h>
#include <IL/ilu.h>
#include "LSpriteSheet.h"

int add = 0;
int zoom = 0;
int factor = 0;
int factor2 = 0;
float y = 0.f;
int scroll = 0;
GLfloat gCameraX = 0.f, gCameraY = 0.f, gCameraZ = 0.f;

//Sprite texture

LSpriteSheet gArrowSprites;
LSpriteSheet gSamusSprites;

bool initGL()
{
    //Initialize GLEW
GLenum glewError = glewInit();
if( glewError != GLEW_OK )
{
    printf( "Error initializing GLEW! %s\n", glewGetErrorString( glewError ) );
    return false;
}

//Make sure OpenGL 2.1 is supported
if( !GLEW_VERSION_2_1 )
{
    printf( "OpenGL 2.1 not supported!\n" );
    return false;
 }

//Set the viewport
glViewport( 0.f, 0.f, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

//Initialize Projection Matrix
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho( 0.0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.0, 5.0, -5.0 );

//Initialize Modelview Matrix
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();

glPushMatrix();

//Initialize clear color
glClearColor( 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f );

//Enable texturing
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

glEnable( GL_BLEND );
glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );

//Check for error
GLenum error = glGetError();
if( error != GL_NO_ERROR )
{
    printf( "Error initializing OpenGL! %s\n", gluErrorString(error));
    return false;
}

//Initialize DevIL
ilInit();
ilClearColour( 255, 255, 255, 000 );

//Check for error
ILenum ilError = ilGetError();
if( ilError != IL_NO_ERROR )
{
    printf( "Error initializing DevIL! %s\n", iluErrorString(ilError) );
    return false;
}

return true;
}


bool loadMedia()
{

//Load texture
if( !gArrowSprites.loadTextureFromFile( "SamusM.png" ) )
{
    printf( "Unable to load texture!\n" );
    return false;
}
LFRect clip = { 0.f, 0.f, 330.f, 355.f };

//Top left
clip.x = 0.f;
clip.y = 0.f;
gArrowSprites.addClipSprite( clip );

//Top right
clip = {0.f, 0.f, 310.f, 480.f};

clip.x = 331.f;
clip.y = 0.f;
gArrowSprites.addClipSprite( clip );

clip = {0.f, 0.f, 330.f, 125.f};
//Bottom left
clip.x = 0.f;
clip.y = 355.f;

gArrowSprites.addClipSprite( clip );

clip = { 0.f, 0.f, 330.f, 355.f };

//Top left
clip.x = 0.f;
clip.y = 480.f;
gArrowSprites.addClipSprite( clip );

//Top right
clip = {0.f, 0.f, 310.f, 480.f};

clip.x = 331.f;
clip.y = 480.f;
gArrowSprites.addClipSprite( clip );

clip = {0.f, 0.f, 330.f, 125.f};
//Bottom left
clip.x = 0.f;
clip.y = 835.f;

gArrowSprites.addClipSprite( clip );
//Generate VBO
if( !gArrowSprites.generateDataBuffer() )
{
    printf( "Unable to clip sprite sheet!\n" );
    return false;
}
if( !gSamusSprites.loadTextureFromFile( "SamusG.png" ) )
{
    printf( "Unable to load texture!\n" );
    return false;
}

    while(scroll != 40){
    y += 214.f;
    scroll++;
    if(scroll == 40){
        scroll = 0;
    }
 }

clip = {0.f, 0.f, 213.f, 214.f};

clip.x = 0.f;
clip.y = y;

gSamusSprites.addClipSprite( clip );

if( !gSamusSprites.generateDataBuffer() )
{
    printf( "Unable to clip sprite sheet!\n" );
    return false;
}
return true;
}

void update()
{

}

void render()
{
//Clear color buffer

glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();

if(add == 0){
    if(zoom < 101){
    double const f_zoom = 1.0 + 0.1 * zoom;
    glScaled(f_zoom, f_zoom, f_zoom);
    }
    if(zoom < -10){
    double const f_zoom = 1.0 - 0.1 * zoom;
    glScaled(f_zoom, f_zoom, f_zoom);
    }

 glTranslatef( -100.f, 178.f, 0.f );
 gArrowSprites.renderSprite( 0 );

//Render top right arrow
glTranslatef( +100.f, -178.f, 0.f );
glTranslatef( 1240.f, 240.f, 0.f );
gArrowSprites.renderSprite( 1 );

//Render bottom left arrow
glTranslatef( -1240.f, +240.f, 0.f );
glTranslatef( 620.f, 500.f ,0.f );
gArrowSprites.renderSprite( 2 );

glTranslatef( -620.f, -500.f, 0.f );
glTranslatef( 620.f, 0.f , 0.f );
gSamusSprites.renderSprite( 0 );

}
if(add == 1){
    if(zoom < 101){
    double const f_zoom = 1.0 + 0.1 * zoom;
    glScaled(f_zoom, f_zoom, f_zoom);
    }
    if(zoom < -10){
    double const f_zoom = 1.0 - 0.1 * zoom;
    glScaled(f_zoom, f_zoom, f_zoom);
    }

glTranslatef( -100.f, 178.f, 0.f );
gArrowSprites.renderSprite( 3 );

glTranslatef( +100.f, -178.f, 0.f );
glTranslatef( 1240.f, 240.f, 0.f );
gArrowSprites.renderSprite( 4 );

glTranslatef( -1240.f, +240.f, 0.f );
glTranslatef( 620.f, 500.f ,0.f );
gArrowSprites.renderSprite( 5 );
}

glLoadIdentity();


glutSwapBuffers();

}
void handleKeys( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
//If the user presses q
if( key == 'q' && add == 0)
{
                add++;
}
else if( key == 'q' && add == 1)
{
    add--;
}
    //Update the sprite rectangles so the texture change takes effect
    if( key == 27 ) {
        exit(0);
    }
    if(key == 'a') {
    gCameraX += 8.f;
    factor--;
    factor2++;
    }
    else if (key == 'd') {
    gCameraX -= 8.f;
    factor++;
    factor2--;
    }
    else if (key == 'w') {
    gCameraY += 8.f;
    }
    else if (key == 's') {
    gCameraY -= 8.f;
    }
    else if (key == '+' && zoom != 100) {
    zoom += 1;
    if(factor >= 19) {
    gCameraX -= 64.f;
    }
    if(factor2 >= 33){
        gCameraX += 16.f;
    }
    else{
        gCameraX -= 64.f;
        gCameraY -= 50.f;
    }
    }
    else if (key == '-' && zoom != -9) {
    zoom -= 1;
    if(factor >= 19){
        gCameraX += 64.f;
    }
    if(factor2 >= 33){
    gCameraX -= 32.f;
    }
    else{
    gCameraX += 64.f;
    gCameraY += 50.f;
    }
    }
        //Take saved matrix off the stack and reset it
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glPopMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

//Move camera to position
glTranslatef( gCameraX, gCameraY, gCameraZ );

//Save default matrix again with camera translation
glPushMatrix();
}
```

EDIT: I just tried adjusting the y coordinate value in the for loop and nothing was happening so I tried removing the if statement and still nothing. But if I adjust the y value at the top of my file the texture will change. So why isn't my loop adding to my y value?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's because in your `for`

```
for(int scroll; scroll > 40; scroll++){
```

you declare the `scroll` variable but you don't initialize it.

So `scroll` start with an undefined value that can be greather than 40.

Solution (I suppose): initialize `scroll`.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

**--- EDIT 2016.05.23 ---**

Look at this code

```
    while(scroll != 40){
    y += 214.f;
    scroll++;
    if(scroll == 40){
        scroll = 0;
    }
}

clip = {0.f, 0.f, 213.f, 214.f};

clip.x = 0.f;
clip.y = y;

gSamusSprites.addClipSprite( clip );
```

If `scrool` reach the `while` with a value different from `40`, the `while` never exit and you only increment (forever) `y`.

I suppose you intention was to call  `gSamusSprites.addClipSprite()` (or a similar function) for every iteration of the `while`.

I suppose your intention was to iterate the cycle only 40 times and exit.

If my suppositions are correct, you can try something like [caution: not tested]

```
clip = {0.f, 0.f, 213.f, 214.f};

for (scroll = 0; scroll < 40; ++scroll, clip.y += 214.f )
    gSamusSprites.addClipSprite( clip ); // or a different function?
```

Comment: I initialized the scroll variable by doing `= 0` after it(stupid mistake) but nothing changed. so that brings me back to square one. Any clue how to get this to work?

Comment: @PochetTNT - sorry: I had not looked carefully at it yesterday. But... if you initialize `scroll` with 0, the `scroll > 40` test is false and the body of the `for` is never executed; your intention was `scroll < 40` ? In this case the `if ( scroll >= 40 ) scroll = 1;` is never executed. But if the test of the `for` is `test >= 40`, when `test == 40` the internal `if` set `scroll = 1`, so the `for` never exit. Really: I don't understand what were your intention with that `for`

Comment: Ok so I fixed my while loop crashing issue by reinstalling glew(pain in the a**). Now I'm doing the same code but in a while loop. My new issue is when I add the if statement to the loop(for or while) it crashes my program but without the if statement it gets stuck on the last frame. What I'm trying to accomplish through using the loop is getting it to scroll through my "gif" which I turned into a vertical tilesheet so it's animated.

Comment: that put's my current loop code like this    `while(scroll != 40){
        y += 214.f;
        scroll++;
        if(scroll == 40){
            scroll = 0;
        }
}`

Comment: @PocketTNT - but this (if I'm not wrong) is a never ending loop. From zero to 39 to zero, to 39 again, to zero, etc.

Comment: It is but it causes a crash.

Comment: Do you know a good alternative to what I'm doing or a way to fix it?

Comment: @PocketTNT - I don't understand how it can cause a crash. And I don't understand what, exactly, you want obtain. But, if you edit your question adding the exactly current code, tomorrow I try to give a look.

Comment: @PocketTNT - I continue to don't understand the meaning of your `for`; you add `214.f` to `y` but... what do you do with `y`? Nothing, if I'm not wrong. I suppose you should use `y`.

Comment: sorry forgot I changed `clip.y = y;` to `clip.y = 0.f;` to stop the crashing. It should be more clear now.

Comment: The code is good but I'm trying to run it in an infinite loop which causes crashing. Can you make that loop repeat itself after a certain amount of time has passed?

Comment: I added `glutSwapBuffers()` to the loop and now instead of crashing with a white screen it crashes on a black screen.